# CSS Flexbox columns are overflowing

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, overflow

I want to build a layout with CSS flexbox and I got into a problem while building a calculator.

I have a `#controller` that contains all my buttons on the calculator. The "=" button's size is twice the other buttons (vertically).

The bottom of the layout is like this (I cant upload pictures)
...

| 4 | 5 | 6 | / |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | = |
| . | 0 | % | = |

So I created div "rows" for the normal buttons in which they are set to `flex-grow: 1;` so it stays responsive to the width.

I made a div container called ".bottom" for the left and right "columns". The left contains the rows and the normal sized buttons, and the right contains the "=" button.

**Problem:

Both columns inside the `.bottom` part are overflowing from the `#controller` with their content.**

I don't necessarily want to wrap my layout. I figured out maybe I should create only columns, not rows, but before that I wanted to ask for advice. Thank you in advance!

HTML bottom part:

```
<div id="calculator">
  <!-- screen of calculator -->
  <div id="controller">
    <!-- upper part of button rows -->
    <div class="bottom">
      <div class="columnLeft">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="button">1</div>
          <div class="button">2</div>
          <div class="button">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="button">.</div>
          <div class="button">0</div>
          <div class="button">%</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="columnRight">
        <div class="longButton">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#calculator, #controller {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#calculator {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}

#controller .row {
  display: flex;
}

#controller .bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#controller .bottom .columnLeft, #controller .bottom .columnRight {
  display: flex;
}

#controller .bottom .columnLeft {
  flex-grow: 3;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#controller .bottom .columnRight {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.button, .longButton{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect task for `CSS-Grid` over `Flexbox` as you need to control both directions at the same time.

Comment: So in what task would you recommend flexbox more? Actually I haven't met with CSS-Grid before.
EDIT: I looked into it, sry for asking beforehand.
I just really wanted to know if I'm the one not understanding this layout method.

Comment: Flexbox has some advantages such as `flex-grow/shrink` and better compatibility in IE (which is diminishing now since it is officially deprecated). The major downside is that Flexbox only is able to control one direction. Either height or width but never both. CSS-Grid can control both directions at the same time which creates a table-like layout. This however is also a downside as elements can only be placed directly inside that grid and are less flexible. However, in your case you want to align buttons in a table-like layout and as such grid would do that for you by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place all the buttons in a `CSS-Grid`. To let an element occupy 2 rows you can use `grid-row: span 2` on that element.

```css
.calculator-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  gap: 0.5em;
  max-width: 200px;
}

.row-2 {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator-grid">
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
  <button>/</button>
  
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button class="row-2">=</button>
  
  <button>.</button>
  <button>0</button>
  <button>%</button>
  <!-- empty for equal button -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid is the way to go here. You can use grid-template areas to span cells like the calculator example I've done below. There's a great primer [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) and a good video by Kevin Powell [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU)

I've knocked up an example to get you started.

```css
.bottom {
      display: grid;
      width: 50%;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
      grid-template-areas: "b4 b5 b6 bdiv""b1 b2 b3 bequals""bdot b0 bpercent bequals";
      gap: 0.5rem;
    }

    .bottom>div {
      /* aspect-ratio: 1; */
      background-color: lightgray;
      display: grid;
      place-items: center;
      padding-block:1rem;
      transition: background-color 0.2s;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .bottom>div:hover {
      background-color:darkgray;
    }

    .button-1 {
      grid-area: b1;
    }

    .button-2 {
      grid-area: b2;
    }

    .button-3 {
      grid-area: b3;
    }

    .button-4 {
      grid-area: b4;
    }

    .button-5 {
      grid-area: b5;
    }

    .button-6 {
      grid-area: b6;
    }

    .button-div {
      grid-area: bdiv;
    }

    .button-percent {
      grid-area: bpercent;
    }

    .button-dot {
      grid-area: bdot;
    }

    .button-long {
      grid-area: bequals;
    }
```

```html
<div id="calculator">
    <!-- screen of calculator -->
    <div id="controller">
      <!-- upper part of button rows -->
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="button-4">4</div>
        <div class="button-5">5</div>
        <div class="button-6">6</div>
        <div class="button-div">/</div>
        <div class="button-1">1</div>
        <div class="button-2">2</div>
        <div class="button-3">3</div>
        <div class="button-dot">.</div>
        <div class="button-0">0</div>
        <div class="button-percent">%</div>
        <div class="button-long">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: way too much CSS. Instead of hardcoding all the placements with `grid-area`, you should simply make use of `span 2`

Comment: Every day is a school day, as they say. Thanks. Your solution is better than mine. Have an uptick

Comment: Wow! I guess I wanted to achieve too much with a tool to another purpose. Your code helped me a lot in showing a different way. Imma start rebuilding it by your recommendation. Thank you! Have a nice day! :D

Comment: You're welcome Steve. Have a look at tacoshy's solution too though. He uses much less css than me and is the way to go imho. Definitely watch the video, Kevin Powell is pretty good at explaining css which for years had me thoroughly stumped (and still does occasionally haha)

Comment: Oh, yea it didn't refresh that code. Sry but since you agreed to it and that could be the "final product" I'm going to give the solution to him. But I also give an upvote to you too.